# UDP server socket can't parse all received data

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, server, buffer, pickle

I'm implementing client-server model using **UDP**. The client sends the server data, and in addition to receiving it, the server also need to parse it. Now, if I'm not parsing the data after receiving it the server writes to the file 100% of the data. But when parsing it, it gets delayed and some data doesn't written to the output file.

Server code:

```
        while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

            #I used pickle since the data is an array
            csv_writer.writerow(pickle.loads(data))


            #Stating to parse the data now:
            arr = pickle.loads(data) <---- The data I need to parse is an array

            # If the key exists in the dictionary,
            # increment the value by one
            currentMessageID = arr[0]
            if (dictOfMessageID.has_key(currentMessageID)):
                dictOfMessageID[currentMessageID] += 1

            # # If the key doesn't exists in dictionary
            # # add the key-value pair
            else:
                dictOfMessageID[currentMessageID] = 1
```

How can I solve this? the server still needs to write all the data and parse it
OR am I missing something and UDP packets will get lost in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would try is increasing your UDP socket's incoming-data-buffer (via e.g. `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 128*1024)`) so that the chances of it overflowing while you are parsing data is reduced.

If that's not sufficient, with some more work you can separate the receiving and parsing of the data, by adding the received packets to an list/Queue (instead of parsing them right away) and either parsing them later (after all the packets have been received) or in a separate (lower-priority) thread so that the receiving of incoming packets won't get delayed.

If that still doesn't give you sufficient reliability, then you might want to redesign your system to use a TCP stream rather than UDP packets, since a TCP stream will automatically reduce the transmission speed to match the receiving program's speed, and will automatically resend packets as necessary if/when they get dropped for any reason.

Note that UDP packets can and will get lost for any reason, there is no situation in which UDP packets are guaranteed to be delivered.  If you're going to use UDP, that's a fact of life that you will either have to put up with or find some mechanism to recover from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll use that. but is it reasonable that out of 65,000 packets I only got 42,000 (when parsing the data)?

Comment: There aren't any guarantees on anything, so it's hard to say what is "reasonable".  Assuming you have control over the sending code, you can experiment with slowing down the rate of transmission (e.g. by putting a sleep() call after each send() call) and see what effect that has on how many packets get dropped, but keep in mind that your measurements will be specific to your hardware and likely won't be valid for other setups.  One thing to watch out for, if your sender is using non-blocking I/O, is that it's easy to overflow the sending socket's buffer and lose lots of packets that way.